# How to solve the problem of some content not displaying when using flowdocument to print preview in WPF, such as livecharts2?

Tags: wpf

How to solve the problem of using livecharts2 in WPF flowdocument and not displaying its content in print preview? Thank you.

**1.FlowDocument1.xaml:**

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
              xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF" 
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.Start.Assets.Prints"
              ColumnWidth="400" FontSize="14">
   
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">
        <Run Text="{Binding Name}"></Run>
    </Paragraph>
    <BlockUIContainer>
        <Grid Background="#888">
            <lvc:CartesianChart Height="300" Series="{Binding Series1}" XAxes="{Binding XAxes1}" YAxes="{Binding YAxes1}" />
        </Grid>
    </BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>
```

**2.MainViewModel.cs:**

```
var printPre = new PrintPreView("Assets/Prints/FlowDocument1.xaml", DeviceInfo); printPre.ShowDialog();
```

**3.PrintPreView.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.Start.Views.PrintPreView"         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"          
xmlns:lvc="clrnamespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF"          
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.Start.Views"         
mc:Ignorable="d"         Title="" Height="450" Width="800">     
    <Grid>         
        <DocumentViewer Name="viewer" />     
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

**4.PrintPreView.xaml.cs:**

```
public PrintPreView(string fileName, DeviceInfo data)
{
InitializeComponent();
var flowDocument = (FlowDocument)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
flowDocument.DataContext = data;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =\>
{
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Package package = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
Uri DocumentUri = new Uri("pack://InMemoryDocument.xps");
PackageStore.RemovePackage(DocumentUri);
PackageStore.AddPackage(DocumentUri, package);
XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Fast, DocumentUri.AbsoluteUri);

        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
        var paginator = (flowDocument as IDocumentPaginatorSource).DocumentPaginator;
        writer.Write(paginator);
    
        viewer.Document = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    
        xpsDocument.Close();
    }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[replaced with new ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGbGf.png)

in the file name of 'PrintPreView.xaml.cs', the 'flowDocument.DataContext' is null, you should let it bind to its ViewModel.

I used your code and make a program demo, it runs well, displaying its content in print preview successfully!

here is the demo github: https://github.com/zzp229/StackOverFlow-1-livecharts2-

Comment: the key is to display the CartesianChart in flowDocument1. xaml, and I noticed that it has been commented out in your code.